# Jews and makkas choshech

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, egypt, plagues-makkos

I heard someone say that the Jews who didn't want to leave Egypt died during makkos choshech.

1) Does anyone know where the source for this can be found?

2) Did four-fifths our people die during this event or was it more?

Comment: @sam: Where in Shemos Rabbah is it located? Is this the answer for both questions?

Comment: [Shemot 13:18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9874#showrashi=true&v=18)

Comment: What was the reason that four-fifths of our people died during makkas choshech?

Answer (score 1):

The members of כלל ישראל who were rishaim (as rashi says in chumash), as well as (unless they are one and the same) those who had patrons from amongst the mitzriim and  didn't want to leave died in מכת חשך, as we see in 'שמות רבה י"ד ג -

לְפִי שֶׁהָיוּ פּוֹשְׁעִים בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁהָיָה לָהֶן פַּטְרוֹנִין מִן הַמִּצְרִיִּים וְהָיָה לָהֶן שָׁם עשֶׁר וְכָבוֹד וְלֹא הָיוּ רוֹצִים לָצֵאת, אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אִם אָבִיא עֲלֵיהֶן מַכָּה בְּפַרְהֶסְיָא וְיָמוּתוּ, יֹאמְרוּ הַמִּצְרִיִּים כְּשֵׁם שֶׁעָבַר עָלֵינוּ כָּךְ עָבַר עֲלֵיהֶן, לְפִיכָךְ הֵבִיא עַל הַמִּצְרִיִּים אֶת הַחשֶׁךְ שְׁלשָׁה יָמִים כְּדֵי שֶׁיִּהְיוּ קוֹבְרִין מֵתֵיהֶם וְלֹא יִהְיוּ רוֹאִין אוֹתָן שׂוֹנְאֵיהֶם וְיִהְיוּ מְשַׁבְּחִין לְהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא עַל כָּךְ

And, as it says in the מכילתא דרבי ישמאל י"ב: כ"ה -

שום שנאמר וחמושים עלו בני ישראל, אחד מחמשה ויש אומרים אחד מחמשים ויש אומרים אחד מחמש מאות עלו. ר' נהוראי אומר, העבודה, ולא אהד מחמש מאות עלו, שנאמר רבבה כצמח השדה נתתיך וגו' (יחזקאל כו). וכתיב ובני ישראל פרו וישרצו (שמות א), שהיתה אשה אחת יולדת ששה בנים בכרס אחד – ואתה אומר אחד מחמש מאות עלו

there is a machlokes if it was one fifth, one fiftieth, or one five-hundredth.